# PDO Cannot connect to MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

I am using Yii as my PHP framework. I'm trying to use Gii to generate a model, the problem is I can't event get to the page to generate models because of this error:

```
PDO::__construct() [<a href='pdo.--construct'>pdo.--construct</a>]: [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysqld.sock)
```

My php.ini looks like:

```
upload_max_filesize = 12M 
post_max_size = 12M
mysql:host=localhost;port=3306
mysql:unix_socket=/tmp/mysqld.sock
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysqld.sock
```

mysql.sock does exist in /tmp/ (installed from MySQL package via MySQL.com). MySQL is running, I'm on Mac OS X 10.6. The root password is not set.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your ini file you have `mysqld.sock` and in your post you have it as `mysql.sock`.  Which one is it?

Comment: Holy crap. Fat ringer surprise... Thanks, that did the trick. submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.